# checking an object to make sure it is not null

Tags: java, null

i am trying to check to make sure an object I am creating is not null, currently i have

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Driver2 {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

    //creates cars
    Vehicle aCar= new Vehicle();
    Vehicle bCar= new Vehicle();
    Vehicle cCar= new Vehicle();

    //creates trucks
    Truck aTruck= new Truck();
    Truck bTruck= new Truck();
    Truck cTruck= new Truck();

    //data checks
    boolean aCarCheck= false;
    boolean bCarCheck= false;
    boolean cCarCheck= false;
    boolean nameCheck1= false;
    boolean nameCheck1Full= false;
    boolean nameCheck2= false;
    boolean nameCheck2Full = false;
    boolean nameCheck3= false;
    boolean nameCheck3Full= false;
    boolean aTruckCheck= false;
    boolean bTruckCheck= false;
    boolean cTruckCheck= false;

    while(!nameCheck1Full){

    System.out.println("Enter first persons name");
    Person owner1= new Person(keyboard.next());
    aCar.setOwner(owner1);
    if (owner1==null){
        System.out.println("Please enter a name!");
        nameCheck1Full=false;

}else{
    nameCheck1Full=true;
}

    System.out.println("You entered: " + aCar.getOwner());

    while(!nameCheck2Full){
        System.out.println("Please enter second persons name");
        System.out.println("Please enter the same name for person 2 as person 1");
        Person owner2= new Person(keyboard.next());
        bCar.setOwner(owner2);
        if (bCar.equals(bCar))
        nameCheck2Full=true;
    }
}
}
}
```

i have been looking for a bit and cant seem to find a good solution that works for me

i'm probably way off since that's how everything has been with this project and i'm so close to giving up but need to finish this

Comment: and what is the challenge that you've faced with your current code?

Comment: How would `owner1` be `null`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Is there any problem in your current code? Or you are just looking to optimize it?

Comment: You should *NOT* have `aCar`, `bCar`, `cCar`, etc.  You should *NOT* have `aCarCheck` etc.  Just add your vehicles to Java "Lists".  For example: `List<Vehicle> trucks = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();  trucks.add(new Truck());`.  It's cleaner ... and checking for "null" becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @nullpointer checking to make sure the owners name is not null; that the user actually entered a name

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if the user does not enter any value wouldnt it be null?

Comment: @paulsm4 that method sounds like much more work for what im trying to accomplish, im just making 3 people, 3 cars, and 3 trucks dont see a reason to use an array

Comment: @BlitzNinja29 i need to use data validation to make sure the user actually entered a name for the owners name

Comment: Hi @CarmineA, then why don't you just use String data type then check if it is empty or not?

Comment: @BlitzNinja29 how would i do that?

Comment: Point of clarification -- objects are *never* null. Variables can be, but never objects.

Answer (score 0):

You check against null with:

```
if (myObject == null) ...
```

Sometimes what you really want to do is check against empty values:

```
String myValue = ...
if (myValue == null || "".equals(myValue)) ...
```

Comment: but if im setting the value to an object how would i make it a string?

Comment: That's a completely different kind of pudding. Have a look at the Object.toString() method (in the Javadocs)

Comment: i do have a toString method

Comment: While `"".equals(myValue)` is a nice [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), I would prefer [`String.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--)